# QNetworkAccessManager and FTP Response 421: Too many connections from your IP

Tags: qt, qt5, qtnetwork

I'm using `QNetworkAccessManager::get()` to get ~200 small files via ftp protocol in a parallel threads.

As I expected I'm getting a FTP Response 421: "There are too many connections from your internet address" message from server after 20 files completed. I see this message in Wireshark's package capture. But I'm not getting it in `QNetworkReply::errorOccurred` or `QNetworkReply::finished`. This is a problem.

I don't mind to make a timebreak when getting such message but it seems to not be exposed to the developer. Am I correct? Perhaps `QFtp` allows to react on such responses?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) -> This will let us know if you are opening 1 connection for every file you want to download. I mean you say *in a parallel threads*, that is an inconvenient typo there ... is it 1 thread or several (how many)?

Comment: 4 QThreads with QNetworkReply and QEventLoop instances in each. A processing queue filled with 180 ftp urls. All at same ftp server. Each thread take an url from the queue. The process stops after 20-25 urls. None of the QNetworkReply signals is emited at this point. At Wireshark I see 4 last incoming TCP packets containing response "421 There are too many connections from your internet address." sent by the server, one per each thread.

Comment: And your code...?